# What does SQUID stand for?

Tags: windows, registry, squid, sid, clsid

The article below mentions SQUIDs several times but I can't figure out what it stands for. I know what SID and CLSID stand for but not sure about SQUID. Any ideas?

Example from article:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\<SID>\Patches\<SQUID>
```

Article:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/971187

Answer (score 2):

SQUID stands for "squished" GUID

Comment: Thank you so much! That was so fast!